# How do I make index.php will control anything in PHP

Tags: php, structure

Firstly, I don't know what to call this thing :) I want to know the key, structure and example how to achieve my goal.

Example, I don't want create separate file like `register.php, login.php, about.php faq.php`. Here I want the `register, login about, faq ,etc` will handle by `index.php` by example, maybe something like `index.php?p=register`

How do I create page something like that and what this structure called in PHP programming. Let me know.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation. Thanks guys you help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide a more appropriate answer using Neals code, use [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) to filter out non-essential file information:

```
$page = isset($_GET['p'])?basename($_GET['p']):'main';

include_once "$page.php";
```

You could also create a "white list" to ensure that only the proper files get included:

```
 $whiteList = array('faq', 'register', 'profile'); 
 $page = (isset($_GET['p']) && in_array($_GET['p'], $whiteList))?basename($_GET['p']):'main';

 include_once "$page.php";
```

Both ways should be secure, obviously, the white list will be a bit more so. This tact, depending on how you do is generally referred to as "BootStrapping" IE, one entrance page to access the rest.

---

**UPDATE**

To further the security, I would set a variable, `$included` would be sufficient, to add to the pages that are being included. This would prevent direct access to them (assuming that [`register_globals`](http://php.net/register_globals) is turned off like it should be, so something like:

```
 $whiteList = array('faq', 'register', 'profile'); 
 $page = (isset($_GET['p']) && in_array($_GET['p'], $whiteList))?basename($_GET['p']):'main';

 $included = true;
 include_once "$page.php";
```

Then on `$page.php` at the top you would have something like:

```
<?php

if (!$included)
       die('Accessing the file directly is not allowed.');
```

Which would prevent calls to `http://yoursite.com/register.php` from being allowed to dish out the file. This has it's negatives to it. Instead of putting the files you are going to be including in the webroot, I would put them outside of the webroot or in an `.htaccess` protected directory, which would ensure that users could not access them directly and must access them through the index.php.

Comment: I wouldn't use ANYTHING from the URL to pass to the include. I would keep it completely separate. Give it code names if you have to. This is still risky.

Comment: cdburgess, I would call you out on that. I can see how the non-white list method may be risky, but if you can prove to me how the whitelist method is risky, I would gladly retract that and my statements. "Code names" would be more secure, sure. But in reality not necessarily so, generally anyone could figure out a codename, especially if you want it to be somewhat human readable.

Comment: What I am saying is you can pass the page name, but use it to do the look up exclusively... do not use it in the actual include_once().

Comment: I still do not see a difference in using a code name vs the realname, sorry. As long as the file is in the webroot, and not outside of it, people could easily try a few different combinations and gain access to it. That is just my opinion / view. The more secure method would be to store it outside of webroot.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I'm still blur on `$whiteList` part. Let's say I have 30 files. Should I write it one by one in the `array()`?

Comment: user700515, yea, that would be one way to do it. If you have a database you could setup the `$whiteList` in there, or if you have a `config.php` file, you could set it in there, you just need to make sure that however you do it, the `$whiteList` is populated before the `$page` check.

Answer (score 4):

In `index.php?p=register` the part after `?` is called "Query String". PHP will by default parse it for you and provides the superglobal `$_GET`. Just try it out yourself

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the whole thing is called, but if you're using `index.php` like that, it's called a `FrontController`. It's how `MVC` frameworks work:

```
/index.php?q=ctrl/action
/index.php/ctrl/action
/ctrl/action
```

They're all handled by/in `index.php` using `"ctrl/action"`

Comment: OP never stated the OP was using an mvc

Comment: Nor did I. Just a note. `MVC` is always a handy term to remember, isn't it!?

Answer (score 2):

You want to look up php templates or even html iframe.  There are several ways to do this, but some are better than others.  In asp.net it's called a MasterPage.  Hopefully some of these terms help you out.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do something like this, then you can use the get field, but you need to predefine your pages, so for this request: index.php?p=my_page

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['p'];

$pages = array(
   'my_page' => 'mypage.php',
   'another_page' => 'another.php',
   ...
);

$include = $pages[$page];

if(!empty($include)) {
   include_once($include);
} else {
   echo 'No such page';
}
?>
```

This keeps the include completely separate from what is passed on the URL so there is no chance for risky things to get passed.